# How to query comments of tables with Spark SQL?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hive-metastore

I can see the comment of a table among certain other things in SparkSQL like this.

```
DESCRIBE EXTENDED <table_name>
```

But let us say I want a query that shows the comments of all tables in a database. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can do it in 2 ways - 

1. You can check in Hive metadata tables - (hive.TBLS table) 2. create python/java script to connect to hive and use a loop to fetch all comments - tablewise

Comment: spark version ??

Comment: @Srinivas Spark version 3.x

Comment: @KoushikRoy Its not recognizing TBLS.

Comment: hmm, thats a different database - mostly mysql or oracle. You can connect to admin. This is easiest but sometime admin doesnt allow access to metastore so not sure.